# Uploading Image to Imgur on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, base64, imgur

I'm currently trying to build an app that involves the user selecting a photo from their library (or taking a photo) and uploading it to Imgur. I have already built a fairly robust C# Imgur client for Windows Forms applications, but unfortunately porting it to the Windows Phone has been a disaster.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
public void UploadImageAsync(Stream PhotoStream)
{
    try
    {
        WebClient w = new WebClient();
        w.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        string data = "key="+PublicKey+
                "&_fake_status=200"+
                "&type=base64"+
                "&image="+PhotoStreamToBase64(PhotoStream);

        w.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.imgur.com/2/upload", UriKind.Absolute), "POST", data);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

string PhotoStreamToBase64(Stream PhotoStream)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    PhotoStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    byte[] result = memoryStream.ToArray();
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(result);
}
```

What is interesting (and frustrating) is that it appears as though everything is working fine, and I receive a successful response after the upload has completed. However, when trying to view the image after being uploaded, the result looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKgOg.jpg.

This leads me to believe that somehow the image stream is being converted into the byte array incorrectly, or converted into a base 64 string incorrectly. In any case, I cannot get it to work and I am at a total loss. Does anybody have any idea? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You know Imgur gives a complete [C# API example](http://api.imgur.com/examples#uploading_cs), right? If you're using the same logic they are and your code isn't working, it's likely the way you're opening the image is incorrect (or your image is corrupt).

Comment: Ah yes, I did know of the example when I was making my original client. I followed their encoding logic in that example and it worked like a charm, so thank you for pushing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

[SpikeX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334053/spikex) pushed me toward Imgur's [C# API example](https://api.imgur.com/examples#uploading_cs) for image uploading. Borrowing the Base64 encoding logic from their example fixed the issue. Here is the now functional PhotoStreamToBase64 method:

```
string PhotoStreamToBase64(Stream PhotoStream)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    PhotoStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    byte[] result = memoryStream.ToArray();

    string base64img = System.Convert.ToBase64String(result);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < base64img.Length; i += 32766)
    {
        sb.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(base64img.Substring(i, Math.Min(32766, base64img.Length - i))));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```